# Java cmd shutdown CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java, cmd

I was recently trying to restart/shutdown the pc, using a cmd command in java, but get a `CreateProcess error=2`. 
I'm using a StringBuilder cause I need to use the `""` in the cmd command.

```
public class CMDTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        startCmd();
    }

    public static void startCmd() throws IOException {
        String a = "shutdown -s -t 120 -c ";
        String b = "\"Your computer will restart. Cause something .\"";
        String g = "";

        StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        sbuilder.append(a);
        sbuilder.append(b);
        String finall = sbuilder.toString(); 
        System.out.println(finall);

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{finall, g});
        System.out.println(g);

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{finall, g});
        InputStream s = p.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
        String t;

        while ((t = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(t);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder`, is more configurable, you may also find that uses `exec(new String[]{finall, g})` that the OS is actually looking for the command `shutdown -s -t 120 -c "Your computer will restart. Cause something ."` which I'm sure you'll agree, doesn't exist.  Each command and parameter should be it's own element in the `String[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is this code:

```
String command = "shutdown -s -t 120 -c \"Your computer will restart. Cause something.\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Works perfectly, at least on Windows-Systems.

The reason why your code is not working is the `new String[]{finall, g}`. If you pass an array, it will use the first index as the command and the others as params. This will cause into the following:

```
Command: shutdown -s -t 120 -c
Parameter: \"Your computer will restart. Cause something.\"
```

Instead if you pass a string, this will happen:

```
Command: shutdown
Parameters: -s, -t, 120, -c, \"Your computer will restart. Cause something.\"
```

Only the second command can be found, only the standalone shutdown command exists.

Comment: Thank you! It worked now, I already tried, but gave the wrong parameter, thanks for the explanation!